# Setting View Filter Operator to "Greater Than Or Equal To"?

Tags: views

I have a view for which I've set different exposed filters and users can search for objects of different criteria. However, I want some fields to be searched by "Less than/Greater than or equal to" what the user types. I don't have those options in the operator field. Some people seem to have them however.

Comment: I figured it out. My field was set to text so then obviously I couldn't do GT/LT. I switched the field to a CCK one (Integer) and it worked.

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged: if you leave that as an answer and accept it, others will be able to vote on it and use it as a future resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operators you get in a Views exposed form depends on the type of data that is stored. If you store a text string you can't use GT or LT, instead you can use starts with or ends with.

Most likely your problem is that you are storing numbers as text in the database instead of storing them as numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have list (integer) how can i get GT/LT in the few ?