# How to Change View Filter Operator in Views Filter

Tags: hooks, views

I want to Set View Filter Operator to "Less Than Or Equal To" <= in Views Filter of Drupal 7.

**MACHINE NAME** field_guests
**FIELD TYPE List** (integer)
**WIDGET** Select list

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9342/setting-view-filter-operator-to-greater-than-or-equal-to

Comment: I'm not sure that's a duplicate @MutantMahesh...the problem there was the values being stored as text, whereas the field type is `List<Integer>` here